# Push jar-file to gitlab maven packages for CI

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab, repository

I am using maven to write a java program and i have a gitlab repository. Now i want CI to run my junit-tests. So i am creating a maven-docker and try to run them, but it fails because of a missing dependency. The dependency is not available in the docker.
The dependency is in my local maven repository because i added it. There only exists the jar-file and it is not available in a public repository (it is beautyeye-lnf). How can i push the jar-file to gitlab maven packages?
I have read the following article, but wasn't successfull (i do not have a project, just the jar-file)
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/

Is this possible? Or do i not understand the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your maven image and copy your jar file inside. So you can use that image as base image.

Example;

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-8

COPY (dependency files or jar) ./root/.m2/
```

---

```
docker build -t maven-build-image:latest .
```

Comment: so i have to copy the jar to the gitlab-server (e.g. my home?) to use it when creating the base image?

Comment: Not to gitlab-server. Only you need to change base image with that you created.

Comment: but where do i have to put the jar to copy it to the docker? if the runner from gitlab creates the docker, the jar can not be copied from my computer

Comment: Copy your jar under .m2 folder. Create your image than push your docker account by tagging `youraccountname/maven-build-image:latest`. Than use inside gitlab-cli. `image: youraccountname/maven-build-image:latest`